# How to delete "0" values from train data. python

Tags: python, classification

I am working on classification with the fashion mnist dataset with python. The classifier that I want to build is naive Bayes, when running the code I built it seems that the data that I have downloaded has zero values and in some math calculations, the variables are divided by these zero values and I don't want that to happen. So I need a way to "delete" these zero values from the data which I want to classify. An example of what the data looks like :

```
[[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.27450982 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]]
```

The example contains only 10 rows of 60000 data.

I am trying to delete the zeros with this:

```
Xtrain,ytrain),(Xtest,ytest) = fashion_mnist.load_data() # loading data

Xtrain = Xtrain.astype('float32') # I want from this to delete zero values 
Xtest = Xtest.astype('float32')   # and from that
Xtrain=Xtrain/255.0
Xtest=Xtest/255.0


    #Reshaping data 
Xtest=Xtest.reshape(Xtest.shape[0], Xtest.shape[1] * Xtest.shape[2])
Xtrain =Xtrain.reshape(Xtrain.shape[0], Xtrain.shape[1] * Xtrain.shape[2])

naive_bayes = NaiveBayes()
# So before i send this datas to fit function in order to run the classification i am trying 
# with not working way to delete thouse values 
Xtrain_non_zero = []
for i in range(len(Xtrain)):
    for j in range(len(Xtrain)):
        if Xtrain[i][j]!=0:
            Xtrain_non_zero.append(Xtrain[i][j])
print(Xtrain_non_zero)
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand are you not just looking for `Xtrain_non_zero = Xtrain[Xtrain != 0]`?

Comment: @jwalton Hi thank you for your reply, when am doing that am getting an array full of False